# Get country from city function in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, dataset, geo, google-sheets-query

I have a google sheet column with messed location info, I'd like to get a column with name of country. Do you know if there is a simple way of doing it in Google Sheet? Otherwise I'll do a script in Python using a geo DB like https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/
Here a sample of the data I have

```
Lille
Catalunya
Sevilla
Singapore
Moscow
Cologne, Germany
Russia, Moscow
Moscow
West Sussex, England
West Sussex, England
Marseille
Marseille
Edmonds, WA.
France
cebu, philippines
Bordeaux, France
JAPAN
Russia, Moscow
```

Answer (score 0):

A script may make sense but a start at least can be made without, if you have a list of countries (say in ColumnF):

[image: SO49349503 example].

I entered `1` in E1 and in E2 and copied down to suit:

```
=E1+len(F1)+1
```

In B1 and copied down to suit:

```
=iferror(vlookup(max(ArrayFormula(iferror(SEARCH(split(A1," "),{join(",",F$1:F$7)}),0))),E:F,2,0),"")
```